# Error installing Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 5.0 on Sitecore 9.1 instance ['packageinstall:items:ended' event]

Tags: powershell-extensions, installation

I got this error when trying to install SPE 5.0 on my Sitecore 9.1 instance.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I was able to get more details checking the log files:

```
ManagedPoolThread #3 08:35:43 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'packageinstall:items:ended' event.
Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException 
Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Source[1]: Sitecore.ContentSearch 
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, Boolean checkLocation)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.GetContextIndexRanking(IIndexable indexable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Min(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.IContextIndexRankable.GetContextIndexRanking(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0(ISearchIndex i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex.GetContextIndex(IIndexable indexable, GetContextIndexArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex.Process(GetContextIndexArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.GetContextIndexPipeline.Run(ICorePipeline pipeline, GetContextIndexArgs args)
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3.GetEnumerator()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Events.PackagingEventHandler.HandleInstalledItems(List`1 installedItems)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) 


ManagedPoolThread #3 08:35:43 ERROR Installation failed: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'packageinstall:items:ended' event.
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context)
   at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.b__8_0()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.CatchExceptions(ThreadStart start)
```

My SOLR server is up and running and I can open the admin page without any issue.

Did anyone have encounter the same issue in the past?

Comment: Are your indexes healthy? Try rebuild them and install again.

Comment: I've faced a similar issue when installing a Sitecore package. In my case, I was using SXA and sitecore_sxa_master_index and sitecore_sxa_web_index were not configured. I've to manually create Solr cores to resolve the issue.